# Get all XMLs from raw text file?

Tags: java, xml, regex, parsing

I have log file and i need to write programm which get all xml's from this file.
File looks like

```
text
text
xml
text
xml
text 
etc
```

Can you give me advice what is better to use regexp or something else?
Maybe it's possible to do it with dom4j?
If i'll try to use regexp i see next problem that text parts have `<>` tags.

**Update 1:**
XML example

```
  SOAP message:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
 here is body part of valid xml
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
text,text,text,text
symbols etc
  SOAP message:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
 here is body part of valid xml
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
text,text,text,text
symbols etc
```

Thanks.

Comment: ^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]{0,4}+[\n]*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each such part is in separate line, then it should be pretty simple:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s*[^<].*\\n?", "");
```

Comment: Logic is to get all XML, with tags and forget about other text in file

Comment: yeah, i see, but what if xml not on separate line?

Comment: As said in my answer, this will work if... So not else... Update your question with some sample, so I can work with something and I will try to get the right solution for you...

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi - You should use then parser and not regex for this kind of task...

Answer (score 1):

if your XMl is always on one line then you can just iterate over lines checking if it starts with `<`. If so try to parse the whole line as DOM.

```
String xml = "hello\n" + //
        "this is some text\n" + //
        "<foo>I am XML</foo>\n" + //
        "<bar>me too!</bar>\n" + //
        "foo is bar\n" + //
        "<this is not valid XML\n" + //
        "<foo><bar>so am I</bar></foo>\n";
List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>(); // the documents we can find
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
for (String line : xml.split("\n")) {
    if (line.startsWith("<")) {
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes());
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(bis);
            docs.add(doc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem parsing line: `" + line + "` as XML");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Discarding line: `" + line + "`");
    }
}
System.out.println("\nFound " + docs.size() + " XML documents.");
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
for (Document doc : docs) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
    String docAsXml = sw.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("</?description>", "");
    System.out.println(docAsXml);
}
```

Output:

```
Discarding line: `hello`
Discarding line: `this is some text`
Discarding line: `foo is bar`
Problem parsing line: `<this is not valid XML` as XML

Found 3 XML documents.
<foo>I am XML</foo>
<bar>me too!</bar>
<foo><bar>so am I</bar></foo>
```